# Process a node and its optional attributes in a push style

Tags: xslt, xpath, attributes, xslt-1.0

I have an element `t` that has optional attributes `hangText` and `anchor`. I'm trying to process this with an XSLT using push techniques if possible.

The goal is to translate this:

```
<root>
  <t>This is a normal paragraph.</t>
  <t hangText="Sometimes hanging text is needed">in paragraphs.</t>
  <t anchor="p3">Sometimes an anchor is included.</t>
</root>
```

to this [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) output:

```
This is a normal paragraph

**Sometimes hanging text is needed** in paragraphs.

Sometimes an anchor is included.
```

I've tried creating a style sheet that matches `<t>` then matches the attributes separately, but clearly something isn't right yet.

### Attempted solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="t">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@hangText">
    <xsl:text>**</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:text>** </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="@anchor">
    <xsl:element name="a">
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Failing output

```
This is a normal paragraph

in paragraphs.

Sometimes an anchor is included.
```

I could have several patterns matching each possible combination of `<t>` + attributes, but that feels criminal and wouldn't scale with additional attributes.

Comment: Well, your template for `t` elements does not use `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>` at all, so the attributes it might have are never processed at all. On the other doing `<xsl:apply-templates/>` in a template matching an attribute does nothing meaningful as it tries to process child nodes which attribute in XSLT/XPath don't have. So there you need to use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`. And I am not sure why the output is `text` but you try to create a result element, but that might be related to the target format I am not too familiar with.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Great advice, thank you. I'll implement the first part and that should solve it. My goal is to convert to [markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), which is predominantly text based, but does allow inline HTML. If creation of elements is not allowed for text output, I can always just output the literal text of an anchor tag I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martin's comments, I fixed the XLST, as follows:

(comments welcome on whether there's a better way to output the anchor element)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="t">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="t/@hangText">
    <xsl:text>**</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>** </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="t/@anchor">
    <xsl:text>&lt;a name=&quot;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:text>&quot;&gt;&lt;a&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also added `t/` to the match statement, to only match these attributes as part of a `<t>`.

Technically it outputs a final newline I wasn't expecting, but I can live with that. It doesn't affect how the Markdown would be rendered.

Comment: As for creating nodes, you can't output them with the `text` method but of course both `xsl:output` method `html` and `xml` allow you to create result fragments with a mix of text and nodes where you can for instance easily create an anchor with a literal result element in the form of `<a name="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>` inside of your template matching `t/@anchor`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen You are correct, thanks again. Note that I had to use `<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />` to avoid getting an unwanted declaration at the start of my output file.